# How do I do multiple postbacks/ajax updates to a gridview for a single button click?

Tags: gridview, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm working on a search function and am limited by my back end.  I'm trying to speed it up by doing multiple small searches rather than one big search.  What I am currently doing is in the OnClick event, is do the first bit of searching and return the results to a gridview.  If there is more searching to be done, I use AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript to register a small function that clicks the submit button again.

This works but seems like a hack and I feel like there should be a better way.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you looking for a different way of clicking the button or a more efficient way of search?  Say like kicking off a background function that does multiple async queries to pull the data in chunks?  or something of that ilk

Comment: @BryanRoberts The second, kicking of a background function that does multiple async queries

Comment: The "correct" way would be to use Paging in order to speed up the search: Return first 20 results then hit "Next Page" if you want 20 more search results...

Comment: @FrancisP if I had total control over the backend, I would. However, because of the way I have to do queries on the back end, it would be impossible to determine how many pages to show in the paging section without doing the full query,  which is what I am trying to avoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Timer like this:

```
    <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="timer1" Interval="1000"
   ontick="timer1_Tick" Enabled="false" />
```

Then in the Button's onClick event, I started a thread running to perform the search and started the timer.

```
timer1.Enabled = true;
ThreadStart ts = continueSearch;
Thread thread = new Thread(ts);
thread.Start();
```

And in the timer1_Tick handler:

```
if(Session["SearchResults"] != null)
{
    DataView dv = (DataView)Session["SearchResults"];
    dv.Sort = (string)Session["SortExpression"] + (string)Session["SortDirection"];
    gvResults.DataSource = dv;
    gvResults.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first option that comes to mind is an extra layer of complexity but would probably gain your the best user experience by using ajax to pull sets of results as many times as needed using a small service to provide the data.  I provided that example with a little bit of jquery to show the call.

```
searchRequest = $.ajax({
            url: '/GetSearchData.svc',
            data: { searchText: 1 },
            traditional: true,
            success: function(data) {

                // Do something with returned data or kick off another async request
        });
```

This would allow you to pull the raw data in any size or chunks that you want.  Or to attach them to another event such as scroll to add items over time.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not very familiar with jQuery.